# Proving whether or not a certain recursively defined sequence is a Cauchy sequence or not

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

**Question:**

Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be a recursively defined sequence defined as:
$$x_{1} = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$x_{n+1} = \frac{1-x_{n}}{4}$$

I want to show first that $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}| \le \frac{1}{4}|x_{n}-x_{n-1}|$. Using this, I have to prove that the sequence is Cauchy and then find its limit. Here is what I have done:

***Part 1:***

$$|x_{n+1}-x_{n}| = \left|\frac{1-x_{n}}{4} - \frac{1-x_{n-1}}{4}\right| \\
=\left|\frac{-x_{n}}{4} + \frac{x_{n-1}}{4}\right| 
= \frac{1}{4}|-x_{n}+x_{n+1}|$$

But, I do not know how to go from this equality to the inequality that the question has. How may I manipulate the equation so that the $=$ changes to a $\le$?

***Part 2:***

Now as for the second subpart where I have to show that the sequence is Cauchy, I am not sure where to start, so I started with the definition of Cauchy sequence, which is as follows:

A sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ is called a Cauchy sequence if $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists      N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. if $m,n \ge N$, then
$$|a_{m}-a_{n}| < \epsilon$$
But the problem I face is that if I try to use this definition and try to apply it here, I am getting that:
$$x_{m}-x_{n} = \left|\frac{-x_{m-1}}{4}+\frac{x_{n-1}}{4}\right|$$
But after this, how can I use my previous result to prove that this is always bounded by $\epsilon$?

Could someone help me?

Comment: $$|x_{n + 1} - x_{n}| = \left|\frac{1 - x_n}{4} - \frac{1 - x_{n - 1}}{4}\right| = \left|\frac{1}{4}\left(1 - x_n - 1 + x_{n - 1}\right)\right| = \frac{1}{4}\left|x_{n - 1} - x_{n}\right| = \frac{1}{4}|x_{n } - x_{n - 1}|.$$

Comment: @EkeshKumar But how to get the $\le$ not =?

Comment: If it's $=$, then it's also $\leq$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have found $|x_{n+1}-x_n| =\frac14|-x_n+x_{n-1}| = \frac14|x_n-x_{n-1}|$, which satisfies the inequality. If you insist, write $|x_{n+1}-x_n| \le |x_{n+1}-x_n| = \frac14|x_n-x_{n-1}|$ and now you have the inequality.

Using this we see that for any $n$:

$$|x_{n+1}-x_n|\le\frac14|x_n-x_{n-1}| \le \frac1{4^2}|x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}| \le\cdots\le\frac1{4^{n-1}}|x_2-x_1|=\frac1{2^{2n-2}}\cdot\frac38 = \frac3{2^{2n+1}}$$

The "$\cdots$" can be made rigorous via induction on $n$.

Now suppose $m > n$. Then

\begin{align}|x_m-x_n| &\le |x_m-x_{m-1}| + |x_{m-1}-x_{m-2}| + \cdots + |x_{n+1}-x_n|\\
&=\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}|x_{k+1}-x_k|\\
&\le\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\frac{3}{2^{2k+1}}\\
&<\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{3}{2^{2k+1}}\\
&=\frac {3}{2^{2n+1}}\div\left(1-\frac14\right)\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n-1}}\end{align}

Using this upper bound, it should be easy to find the $N \in \mathbb N$ for any arbitrary $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: Sorry but for $x_{m}- x_{n}$ how do you get also those terms that it is less than?

Comment: That is the triangle inequality.

Comment: Sorry, what form of the triangle inequality? The form I knew if |a+b| < |a| +|b|

Comment: A general form: $|a_1 + a_2 + \dots  + a_n| \le |a_1| + |a_2| + \dots + |a_n|$.

Comment: I got it thanks!

Comment: Do you know how I can find the limit?

Comment: Suppose the limit is $L$ (which exists since the sequence is Cauchy). Then $\lim_n a_n =\lim_n a_{n+1}=L$ and thus $L = \frac{1-L}4$ by taking limits on both sides of the recursive definition. That gives the limit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116025/discussion-between-wolf-bear-and-player3236).

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be the function defined for all $x \in [0,1]$ by $$f(x)=\frac{1-x}{4}$$

First, $f$ is well-defined because it is decreasing over $[0,1]$, and $f(0), f(1) \in [0,1]$. Because $x_1 = 1/2 \in [0,1]$, you deduce by an easy induction that the sequence $x_{n+1} = f(x_{n-1})$ is well-defined and takes all its values in $[0,1]$.

For any integer $n \geq 1$, the MVT applied to the function $f$ between $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$ gives $$|x_{n+1}-x_n|=|f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})| = \frac{1}{4}|x_n -x_{n-1}| \quad \quad (*)$$

(because $f' \equiv -1/4$ over $[0,1]$). This is the first part.

Now, for every integers $q>p$, you can see by an easy induction (using the equality $(*)$), that
$$|x_q-x_p|= \frac{1}{4^{p-1}}|x_{q+1-p}-x_1| \leq \frac{1}{4^{p-1}}$$

This proves that the sequence is Cauchy, and you are done.

Comment: How to do it without using MVT?

Comment: Also can you show how you did the part using "easy induction"?

Comment: I used MVT because this is the general theorem which works in such situations, but here, since the function $f$ is linear, you can make the calculation by hand, directly (so no need of MVT). For inductions, see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction This is a very classical way of proving some properties with integers, you should learn about that !